# Strange behavior of MID and zero length string in Access

Tags: ms-access

I'm baffled. I understand the basics of the difference between a zero length string and a null value, but I don't understand what is happening here.

I have a table in access that contains imported information from the body of an email from outlook CONTENTS, that I then use an append query to split information in the email's body into a second more usable table. For example, if the body of the email has TITLE: 10 FEET UNDER and AUTHOR: JOHN DOE, it will retrieve "10 FEET UNDER" using a MID function to capture everything between TITLE: and AUTHOR:.

All was well until a staff member using the program reported bugs occurring due to the rare occasions the text after TITLE: would be blank.

I ran various tests, and for reasons I do not understand at all, running a LEN on the MID function for the 'blank' title gives a result of 2.

Yet, there are no spaces, it is not recognized as a null, and what is appended acts like a zero length string.

I can set criteria by LEN([TITLE]) <> "2" to get rid of the entries that are 'blank', but it seems inelegant. Why is it generating a LEN of 2 when what is appended to the new table under title looks and acts like a zero length string??

If it helps, the destination's table is set to 'Allow Zero Length String = No' for Title, though it doesn't seem to listen to that rule.

Can someone explain to me what is going on?

```
      Title:Mid([Contents],InStr([Contents],"Title:")+10,InStr([Contents],"Author:")-(InStr([Contents],"Title:")+10))
```

Answer (score 0):

Inclined to think there are non-printing characters saved, such as CrLf which will have a Len() of 2.

What do you mean by 'acts like zero-length string'?